# Grant Databricks Workspace access to Unity Catalog Storage Credential

Tags: databricks-unity-catalog

I have unity catalog with a storage credential for accessing a storage account in Azure.

In databricks I have a notebook which accesses data of the storage account via the storage credential. Therefore, I grant my user read access to the storage credential: this works. However, now I want to run the databricks notebook in job (e.g. triggered periodically): which identidy is used in such cases for accessing the storage credential?

Thank you!